# Can I configure my Sony A57 screen and viewfinder display to brighten with a manual flash, just like with the popup flash?

Tags: flash, sony, camera-settings, yongnuo

When I pop up the built-in flash on my Sony Alpha 57, the LCD and electronic viewfinder brighten up a lot, so I can focus properly in low light situations. However, when I put on my Yongnuo 560 mkII, this doesn't happen. Is there any way to change this behavior or is it standard behavior when an external flash is attached? I looked at the camera settings, but didn't see anything that would appear to affect this and without this effect, I can't see anything on the screen or viewfinder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently, I bought a Sony Alpha α68, and had the same problem. When I use an external non-TTL flash (manual only), the EVF is very dark, and I can't see the model.

But the solution is in the menu of the camera. Follow this procedure to fix the issue:

- Go to Menu
- Go to the gear icon
- Go to second (2) menu
- Go to the **Live View Display** option. The default option is `Setting Effect On`. Change this option to `Setting Effect Off`.

This setting changes the EVF to display like a camera with a pentaprism. It works for me on my Sony Alpha α68.

I hope this configuration works for you.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I dont know why i didnt think of this myself.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, that Yongnuo is a manual flash. While I am not experienced with Sony Alpha cameras, I am assuming that it is unable to simulate any brightening the flash unit may provide through the EVF or LCD because the flash is not communicating any information to the camera. Manual flashes must be manually configured. My best suggestion would be to go into the camera's settings and increase the brightness of the EVF and the LCD to see if that helps.